# Recurrence Table with HoldForm

Tags: recursion

Consider:

$$a_1=\sqrt{2}\qquad\text{and}\qquad a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2a_n}$$

I can do this:

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == Sqrt[2 a[n]], a[1] == Sqrt[2]}, a, {n,5}]
```

Now, is there a way I can `HoldForm` so that the `RecurrenceTable` command produces this sequence:

$$\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}},... $$

Answer (score 8):

How about translating the recurrence relation into `Nest`?

```
Nest[HoldForm[Sqrt[2 #]] &, Sqrt[2], 4]
```

[image]

---

To generate the sequence, simply turn `Nest` into `NestList`:

```
NestList[HoldForm[Sqrt[2 #]] &, Sqrt[2], 4]
```

[image]

Comment: To generate the sequence use `NestList` rather than `Nest`

Comment: Instead of `HoldForm[]`, use `Defer[]`, so that the results can be copied, pasted, and executed without needing a `ReleaseHold[]`.

Comment: @J.M. I'm curious about "the results can be copied, pasted, and executed" because I tried (using Bob Hanlon's idea below) `seq = NestList[Sqrt[2 #] &, Sqrt[2], 4]`, then `2^FindSequenceFunction[Log[2, seq], n]` and it worked. Then I tried using the Defer command, using `seq = NestList[Defer[Sqrt[2 #]] &, Sqrt[2], 4]`, then `2^FindSequenceFunction[Log[2, seq], n]`, but this time it did not work.

Comment: @David, the `Defer[]` prevents execution. Try this for yourself: run `s = Defer[1 - 1]` in a cell. In a new cell, run `s`. Then, copy the output cell of the first cell (which should be showing `1 - 1`), paste into a new cell, and run it.

Comment: @J.M. Aha! So what I should have read from your comment is to copy and paste the output into the FindSequence function. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear[a]

seqHold = RecurrenceTable[{a[1] == Sqrt[2], 
   a[n + 1] == Sqrt[HoldForm[2 a[n]]]},
  a[n], {n, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

The actual sequence is

```
seq = Map[ReleaseHold, seqHold, Infinity]

(*  {Sqrt[2], 2^(3/4), 2^(7/8), 2^(15/16), 2^(31/32)}  *)
```

Using [`FindSequenceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to determine the closed-form from this sequence

```
a1[n_] = 2^FindSequenceFunction[Log[2, seq], n] // Simplify

(*  2^(1 - 2^-n)  *)
```

Alternatively, using [`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) to find the closed-form

```
a2[n_] = a[n] /. RSolve[
      {a[1] == Sqrt[2], a[n + 1] == Sqrt[2 a[n]]},
      a[n], n][[1]] // Simplify // Quiet

(*  2^(1 - 2^-n)  *)
```

The two approaches are equivalent

```
a1[n] == a2[n]

(*  True  *)
```

**EDIT:** The limit of the sequence is

```
Limit[a2[n], n -> Infinity]

(*  2  *)
```

This can also be obtained using [`FixedPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html)

```
FixedPoint[Sqrt[2 #] &, Sqrt[2.]]

(*  2.  *)
```

Comment: Nice answer. I do have a question. I tried `seq = RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == Sqrt[2 a[n]], a[1] == Sqrt[2]}, 
  a[n], {n, 1, 5}]`, then `FindSequenceFunction[seq, n]` and it didn't work. Now, I know that $2^\log_{2}x=x$, but what made you think to use this fact to get the FindSequence function to work? Can you explain? Thanks.

Comment: @David - `seq` consists only of powers of `2`. The sequence of the exponents is clearly a simpler sequence for `FindSequenceFunction` to deal with, and converting back to powers of `2` is straightforward.

Comment: Aha! That's how you came up with your idea. A very nice move. Thanks.